# Определить тип возвращаемоего значения функции, в зависимости от переданного параметра

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

У меня есть тип:

```typescript
type TaskType = "return professions";
```

И есть описанная функция в интерфейсе:

```typescript
interface IInterfaceName
{
    getReponse(message: string, task?: TaskType): string | string[];
}
```

Моя задача, чтобы функция возвращала не `string | string[]`, а более известный тип. Для текущей задачи, если мы передаем в `taks` значение `"return professions"`, функция должна вернуть `string`, если же я передам `undefined` (или же вызову функцию без передачи параметра), я хочу получить тип `string`.

Я слышал про `infer`, возможно оно окажется решением. Но я не пойму как это написать.

---

```typescript
getResponse("test") // return type: string
getResponse("test", "return professions") // return type: string[]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из личного опыта: Всевозможные проверки в возвращаемом типе приводят к еще большей запутанности, хотя им так же можно найти применение.

В конкретном примере просто перегружается сигнатура, TS сам определит к чему больше подходят аргументы.

```typescript
type TaskType = "return professions";

interface IInterfaceName
{
    getReponse(message: string): string;
    getReponse(message: string, task: TaskType): string[];
    getReponse(message: string, task?: TaskType): string | string[];
}
```

UPD1: Еще примеры:

```js
type TaskType = "a" | "b" 

type TaskTypeObj = {
  type: "a" | "b"
}

type TaskTypeReturns = {
  a: string
  b: string[]
}

interface IInterfaceName
{
    getReponse<T extends (TaskType | undefined)>(message: string, task?: T): T extends undefined ? 123 : (T extends TaskType ? TaskTypeReturns[T] : never);
}

// Для извлечения типа определенного свойства
interface IInterfaceNameV2
{
    getReponse<T extends TaskTypeObj>(message: string, task?: T): T extends {type: infer V} ? (V extends TaskType ? TaskTypeReturns[V] : never) : never;
}

function foo(name: IInterfaceName) {
  const res1 = name.getReponse("xxx", 'a'); // string
  const res2 = name.getReponse("xxx", 'b'); // string[]
  // Обрати внимание, что без перегрузки мы получили не то что ожидаем - а вообще все типы
  const res3 = name.getReponse("xxx"); // string | string[] | 123
}

function fooV2(name: IInterfaceNameV2) {
  const res1 = name.getReponse("xxx", {type: 'a'}); // string
  const res2 = name.getReponse("xxx", {type: 'b'}); // string[]
  const res3 = name.getReponse("xxx"); // string | string[]
}
```

[typescriptlang.org play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=34&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#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-IFuaFsxGYp5ZcAoEoIAhlhos5EAHRSmWpIpYbLtrB9ADkcC7byg311VhMZlLanLlYQq1r2cbCQgyRbbY73aIfdeA5+eus9jMg8AeCCARhB8Zi0VAIUjADwgmKR0L6sJRNMP0LBUHR0MJlPxgGEQMGALhAQSgS9AGkQN8cX+b9YRBf5AIRaEoEfKAHxpHFADYQEEiUxaFLygABaKBsQZHFD0ASRB4IhWl4LRdFgNHMsKyrTZMDrCA52lBdZQgVt22yLB+0HbcTEEQTbFuQg1nWD54xURNkxUVN01FTNsz4Pl80FbNRWLOjxwY6sZwbJsOKXHjO00a0oB7LsRH4rdh1MTgxz0PTp2Y2cjMXOVuJXcy0D4Ls1xsjcBPs3dHPoycmPudz508rjl142yh31YTQocMQoCAA)

UPD2: [Смотри еще](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgZwNY3NAvFARHLUA+2ARngFCkCWAdsBAE4BmcAxtAJJs31OsBycAWwikA3qSgSoAeilRA+CCA+EECCIIB4QBYCEQQAIggDhAogLhBADCB6ogWRB1CqJoOBGEA0HArCDqo1+4HYQU+cCcIFCVaFe7QAaKAMoQH4QDQUVSwMlJT0o+0BeEHVtTUBhEE9xSRkAcwhgACUIMAB7KgQIAAohBAQ4fIAuKARgOmpcgEpm1vaqXOyJfKKS8sqAHhgoCAAPWioAEwQoKvhkVEgCKABXRYgGaggFzoA+Gog6hogeto7g4EQkAH5mmG6oQckp2fmlqAByOD-D6SUFQJ4tW79EFgiSvaZzCCLZb-IjAz6wiQQ3odADaAF0MZibn1cgBuaSyMKAaRB1A4VEpAPIgUEATCD2TRJdLqQAyIJDScEEoBmEEALCChJKOKAPZDBJIWFzuMLs+yCjKuAJQcUxWx0xykAC+5AYu2YwAo5SgDFKpSqVEE1ygHC4jBYEH4Qk6UDEEmYY2AUDoFwAjFBMLahAA6YbFMoVapYGYJrDBQH-ToUmR8jrZH0VP0BhAAJhDUDDEEjBWjYzjCZmSYBaLTlMz-QJ2WyGcUqg0On0Rg8crc4SVKvSaqCIXCkWiETCmgU1kyMTiCRUyVSGW8is0ytVenSrOpgAkQezZ33+i4AZmLpfLIxjlSq8cTafbskAiCCDrc70fqnHQwh-rkrYSBmgCEIEO24jmqCjeIB+qkEAA)

Comment: Я подразумеваю, что `TaskType` будет пополняться другими "названиями", которые могут возвращать другие типы. Наверное это стоило бы добавить в вопрос? Я думал это немного очевидно.

Comment: @OliverPatterson Что значит _другие названия_ ?. TS может определить только тип, и на этом точка. Типом может быть константная строка, но НЕ ПЕРЕМЕННАЯ СТРОКА. Если TaskType содержит константные строки, то для каждой придется писать свою сигнатуру с указанием возвращаемого типа. И я сомневаюсь, что все случаи использования могут указывать константы при вызове функций, подозреваю что это просто список, а значит это просто `string`.

Comment: Допустим я захочу в `TaskType` добавить `"return boolean"` и тогда функция должна вернуть `boolean`. Такое возможно?

Comment: @OliverPatterson Посмотри примеры.

Comment: А вторую версию без объекта нельзя сделать и если не будет передан второй параметр, чтобы функция возвращала `string`?

Comment: @OliverPatterson Это был пример с `infer` для извлечения свойства, он тебе не нужен. Смотри еще пример почему проверка не всегда работает. В сообщение ссылка не поместилась, добавил в ответ.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145129/discussion-between-oliver-patterson-and-alexander-lonberg).

Comment: @OliverPatterson Oliver я в этот подвал с недочатом, только под угрозой жизни полезу. Без обид, но этот раздел сайта следует уничтожить.

Comment: Я сделал на [typescriptlang](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAqBDAzgazc1AXjgCIpgYBXKAOzjCggDNgssBLCGrEgbgCh+oSLDjsaMYFCYYAxqgCSAQTDsAQhBj8A3vzhwA5hQBKrSN2AaYACkkgYALjhYYUcQYCUTgAqMAtuxYwAA8Lm40BgB8AgCQRjCmWOZBVsFocKCSNAAmWHDWmLj4KHAAPnCUOcBM4sDZHpG2mU5h7gA0CNg4APxOaF78MTG+EAFBwYND6ZnAOXlkFNR0DMysHFw8kzHdzq7uANoAulstexGT0fwAvoLiktJyiirsOnpwAEaaTsqqVteCsg28Awqm+zzghFe+k+jjeun0+mwiBoskMJjMG0smia9g6MC6Hjgb308IR+nIVFocAwAHcMOx4JAXKEzgYyrtwgYjo0PAIyTd9DcbvwkSi4ExKrIYJxlhBmWgeT5-IEQgqoXAKUs4CMxsAAHTkLAQAA2ADdgNYSCRqXl+tcgA) упрощенный свой код, помогите исправить.

Comment: @OliverPatterson 1) Реализация делается в классах с точным копированием всех перегрузок из декларации интерфейсов. 2) Если уже и хочется запихнуть в литерал, то явно "обмани" TS способом `as MyType`. 3) Если функция обращается к другой за `Promise`, то `async/await` лишнее - это я не убирал. `await` нужен там где внутри функции ожидается значение, а не передается дальше. 4) Ссылка ниже.

Comment: @OliverPatterson Тут [ссылка](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAqBDAzgazc1AXjgCIpgYBXKAOzjCggDNgssBLCGrEgbgCh+oSLDjsaMYFCYYAxqgCSAQTDsAQhBj8A3vzhwA5hQBKrSN2AaYACkkgYALjhYYUcQYCUTgAqMAtuxYwAA8Lm40BgB8AgCQRjCmWOZBVsFocKCSNAAmWHDWmLj4KHAAPnCUOcBM4sDZHpG2mU5h7gA0CNg4APxOaF78MTG+EAFBwYND6ZnAOXlkFNR0DMysHFw8kzHdzq7uANoAulstexGT0fwAvoLiktJyiirsOnpwAEaaTsqqVteCsg28Awqm+zzghFe+k+jjeun0+mwiBoskMJjMG0smjSGXss1y+UKeAIZQqVRqNDqDSa9lO4QMHRgXV66A8b308IR+nIVFocAwAHcMOx4JAXKEzgZSa0IkdGh4BFybvorvy8pUcDQIAK6Ng4D91Jp-vwkSi4ExKrIYJxlhBxWh5T5-IEQg6oXAeUs4CMxsAAHTkLAQAA2ADdgNYSCQ1azrkA)

Comment: Ужасно не нравится такое решение, с дублированием всего.. И костылем как по мне с `as unknown as IApiBot`, но раз без этого никуда.. что поделаешь. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @OliverPatterson Литерал не позволяет использовать перегрузки, так что либо класс, либо `as`. И ничего плохого в `as` нет, иногда без него вообще никуда.

Comment: Если не займет у вас много времени, можете подобную реализацию показать с использованием класса?

Comment: @OliverPatterson Не помещается. Замени на `bot: new Bot()`. Выше создай класс `class Bot implements IApiBot { ... }`. Кликни кнопкой мыши по ошибке и она тебе автоматом заполнит сигнатуру. Ну и впиши свое тело функции.